# Move Async/Await JSON deserialize result to another function

Tags: c#, json, async-await, task, streamreader

I have this function that can get up to 10 items as an input list

```
public async Task<KeyValuePair<string, bool>[]> PayCallSendSMS(List<SmsRequest> ListSms)
{
    List<Task<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>> tasks = new List<Task<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>>();

    foreach (SmsRequest sms in ListSms)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => SendSMS(sms)));
    }

    var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return result;
}
```

and in this function, i `await` for some JSON to be downloaded and after it's done in deserialize it.

```
public async Task<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> SendSMS(SmsRequest sms)
 {
    //some code
      using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string Json = await rdr.ReadToEndAsync();
            deserializedJsonDictionary = (Dictionary<string, object>)jsonSerializer.DeserializeObject(Json);
        }
    }
    //some code
     return  GetResult(sms.recipient);
 }

public KeyValuePair<string, bool> GetResult(string recipient)
{
    if (deserializedJsonDictionary[STATUS].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true"))
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(recipient, true);
    }
    else // deserializedJsonDictionary[STATUS] == "False"
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(recipient, false);
    }
}
```

**My problem is** in the `return  GetResult();` part in which `deserializedJsonDictionary` is null(and ofc it is becuase the json havent done downloading).

but I don't know how to solve it

I tried to use [ContinueWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-5.0) but it doesn't work for me.

I'm willing to accept any change to my original code and/or the design of the solution

Comment: Why are you using `WebRequest`? (`WebRequest` is ancient and should not be used). Why aren't you using `HttpClient` which supports _real_ async IO? You shouldn't be using `Task.Run` for this either.

Comment: `if (deserializedJsonDictionary[STATUS].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true"))` <-- This is not a good way to parse a boolean value.

Comment: `deserializedJsonDictionary` is not null "because the JSON hasn't finished downloading" - it's because you're incorrectly deserializing the JSON. You need to look at the actual response body text (please post it in your question so we can see it). The `Newtonsoft.Json` library is very forgiving and by default it will return `null` instead of throwing a descriptive exception if the JSON text doesn't match the requested type.

Answer (score 5):

- Unrelated tip: Don't abuse `KeyValuePair<>`, use C# 7 value-tuples instead (not least because they're much easier to read).
- Using a `foreach` loop to build a `List<Task>` is fine - though it can be more succint to use `.Select()` instead. I use this approach in my answer.
- But don't use `Task.Run` with the *ancient* `WebRequest` (`HttpWebRequest`) type. Instead use `HttpClient` which has full support for async IO.
- Also, you should conform to the .NET naming-convention:

  - All methods that are async should have `Async` has a method-name suffix (e.g. `PayCallSendSMS` should be named `PayCallSendSmsAsync`).
  - Acronyms and initialisms longer than 2 characters should be in PascalCase, not `CAPS`, so use `Sms` instead of `SMS`.
  - Use `camelCase`, not `PascalCase` for parameters and locals - and `List` is a redundant prefix. A better name for `ListSms` would be `smsRequests` as its type is `List<SmsRequest>`).
- Generally speaking, parameters should be declared using the least-specific type required - *especially* collection parameters, consider typing them as `IEnumerable<T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` instead of `T[]`, `List<T>`, and so on).
- You need to first check that the response from the remote server actually is a JSON response (instead of a HTML error message or XML response) and has the expected status code - otherwise you'll be trying to deserialize something that is not JSON.
- Consider supporting `CancellationToken` too (this is not included in my answer as it adds too much visual noise).
- Always use `Dictionary.TryGetValue` instead of blindly assuming the dictionary indexer will match.

---

```
public async Task< IReadOnlyList<(String recipient, Boolean ok)> > PayCallSendSmsAsync( IEnumerable<SmsRequest> smsRequests )
{
    using( HttpClient httpClient = this.httpClientFactory.Create() )
    {
        var tasks = smsRequests
            .Select(r => SendSmsAsync(httpClient, r))
            .ToList(); // <-- The call to ToList is important as it materializes the list and triggers all of the Tasks.

        (String recipient, Boolean ok)[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        return results;
    }
}

private static async Task<(String recipient, Boolean ok)> SendSmsAsync(HttpClient httpClient, SmsRequest smsRequest)
{
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage( ... ) )
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        String responseType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType?.MediaType ?? "";
        if (responseType != "application/json" || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expected HTTP 200 JSON response but encountered an HTTP " + response.StatusCode + " " + responseType + " response instead." );
        }

        String jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        Dictionary<String,Object> dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< Dictionary<String,Object> >(jsonText);

        if(
            dict != null &&
            dict.TryGetValue(STATUS, out Object statusValue) &&
            statusValue is String statusStr &&
            "true".Equals( statusStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
        )
        {
            return ( smsRequest.Recipient, ok: true );
        }
        else
        {
            return ( smsRequest.Recipient, ok: false );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `HttpClient httpClient = this.httpClientFactory.Create()` i used `HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();`  becuse my project is 4.6.1 and `httpClientFactory` is from .NET core AFAIK but im getting an eror **underlying connection was closed** ,how can i solve it? @Dai

Comment: added ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;  still the same